# Adding a new node (taking value from another xml file) inside a certain parent node?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a program having the following steps:

1) Get all xml files from a user given path

2) Open each of the files (if any) and search for nodes `<institution>` where it is in the format `<funding-source><institution-wrap><institution>...</institution></institution-wrap></funding-source>`

3) Get the value of the nodes `<institution>` and search the exact value in the [database xml](https://codeshare.io/21bMmz) inside the nodes `<skosxl:literalForm xml:lang="...">`

4) If found, get the attribute value of its parent node `<skos:Concept rdf:about="...">` minus the string **http://dx.doi.org/**

5) Add a node `<institution-id institution-id-type="fundref">` in the xml file after the `<institution>` node with the value like `<funding-source><institution-wrap><institution>...</institution><institution-id institution-id-type="fundref">VALUE of the rdf:about attribute</institution-id></institution-wrap></funding-source>`

Here is a sample [input file](https://codeshare.io/5v0mjm) and the [desired output](https://codeshare.io/5XldEo) for that file.

What I have tried:

```
string pathToUpdatedFile = @"D:\test\Jobs";
var files=Directory.GetFiles(pathToUpdatedFile,"*.xml");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var fundingDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test\database.xml");
    XNamespace rdf=XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
    XNamespace skosxl = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#");
    XNamespace skos=XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#");

    var targetAtt = fundingDoc.Descendants(skos+"Concept").Elements(skosxl+"prefLabel")
        .ToLookup(s => (string)s.Element(skosxl+"literalForm"), s => (string)s.Parent.Attribute(rdf+"about"));
    XDocument outDoc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file),LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
    foreach (var f in outDoc.Descendants("funding-source").Elements("institution-wrap"))
    {
        if (f.Element("institution-id") == null)
        {
            var name = (string)f.Element("institution");
            var x = targetAtt[name].FirstOrDefault(); // just take the first one
            if (x != null)

                f.Add(new XElement("institution-id", new XAttribute("institution-id-type","fundref"),x.Substring(@"http://dx.doi.org/".Length)));
        }
        outDoc.Save(file);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

But it is not working...Can somebody help...

Answer (score 1):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication31
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string DATABASE = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement article = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = article.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XDocument docDatabase = XDocument.Load(DATABASE);
            XElement rdf = docDatabase.Root;
            XNamespace nsSkosxl = rdf.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("skosxl");
            XNamespace nsRdf = rdf.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rdf");

            List<XElement> prefLabels = rdf.Descendants(nsSkosxl + "prefLabel").ToList();
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictLabels = prefLabels.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Descendants(nsSkosxl + "literalForm").FirstOrDefault(), y => (string)y.Element(nsSkosxl + "Label").Attribute(nsRdf + "about"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            List<XElement> fundingSources = article.Descendants(ns + "funding-source").ToList();

            foreach (XElement fundingSource in fundingSources)
            {
                XElement institutionWrap = fundingSource.Element(ns + "institution-wrap");
                string institution = (string)fundingSource;

                if (dictLabels.ContainsKey(institution))
                {
                    institutionWrap.Add(new XElement("institution-id", new object[] { 
                       new XAttribute("institution-id-type","fundref"),
                       dictLabels[institution]
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary doesn't contain : '{0}'", institution);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but there are multiple namespaces in the fundref.xml file, how will `GetDefaultNamespace` know which namespace is required for which node..also **test.xml** is the file that needs to be modified and the data is taken from another xml file **fundref.xml**

Comment: There are no prefixes so it is using the default namespace.  That is why I took the root node and extracted the default namespace.

Comment: I want to check for the contents of the node `institution` and then search that value in the database.xml file and then get the attrib value of that and then put it in the xml file that I want to modify...the value of `<institution>` where it is in the format `<funding-source><institution-wrap><institution>...</institution></institution-wrap></funding-source>` won't always be `<funding-source><institution-wrap><institution>Ford Foundation</institution></institution-wrap></funding-source>`

Comment: What I often do if I can't get the namespace I use following : XElement literalForm = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "literalForm").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Then use : List<XElements> fundingSources = article.Descendants(ns + "funding-source").ToList();  Then foreach(XElement fundingSource in fundingSources){ ....}

Comment: I also need to get the correct `rdf:about` attribute value (from database.xml) for each match of the contents of the node `institution`...maybe you didn't read through my whole question..

Comment: I updated the code. I can't get the database xml file because it is being blocked so I cannot answer rest of question.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer.. but there could be multiple identical values of the node `<skosxl:literalForm xml:lang="en">...</skosxl:literalForm>` in the database but with different value of the attribute `rdf:about` of its parent node `skos:Concept` (thats why I'm taking the first found match and was using `ToLookup`),  won't using the dictionary cause a problem there? the database.xml was just a small sample, the actual file is pretty large..

Comment: Quick fix to dictionary to use : Dictionary<string, List<string>>.  The dictionary lines are the only thing I changed.  Very simple.

Comment: but when I run your code it does nothing?? Have you tested it on my sample input? Also one other thing I noticed in your code, you queried `Element(nsSkosxl + "Label")`, but I want the attribute value of  `<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://dx.doi.org/...">`..

Comment: The group by has x (the key) and y the value (which has the about).  I tested the code.  I put a break point at the end. Then hovered over 'article', clicked on down arrow, and looked at results in xml visualizer.

Comment: the sample input file should be changed to desired output file that I provided in the question and your code does not do that..

Comment: I just did not write using doc.Save(FILENAME);

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for (MODIFIED jdweng's CODE A LITTLE)

```
const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
const string DATABASE = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    XElement article = doc.Root;
    XNamespace ns = article.GetDefaultNamespace();

    XDocument docDatabase = XDocument.Load(DATABASE);
    XElement rdf = docDatabase.Root;
    XNamespace nsSkosxl = rdf.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("skosxl");
    XNamespace nsSkos = rdf.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("skos");
    XNamespace nsRdf = rdf.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rdf");

    List<XElement> prefLabels = rdf.Descendants(nsSkos + "Concept").ToList();
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictLabels = prefLabels.GroupBy(x => (string)x.Descendants(nsSkosxl + "literalForm").FirstOrDefault(), y => (string)y.Parent.Element(nsSkos+"Concept").Attribute(nsRdf + "about").Value.Substring(18))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

    List<XElement> fundingSources = article.Descendants(ns + "funding-source").ToList();

    foreach (XElement fundingSource in fundingSources)
    {
        XElement institutionWrap = fundingSource.Element(ns + "institution-wrap");
        string institution = (string)fundingSource;

        if (dictLabels.ContainsKey(institution))
        {
            institutionWrap.Add(new XElement("institution-id", new object[] {
                                                new XAttribute("institution-id-type","fundref"),
                                                dictLabels[institution]
                                             }));
        }
    }
    doc.Save(FILENAME);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```